# VBA Seleccionar elemento html por classe

Tags: excel, vba, macros, html-select

Necesito acceder a el valor de un input y hacer click en otro con una macro de Excel y necesito seleccionar los inputs mediante su clase, pues no tienen id. He visto googleando que existe el metodo .getElementByClassName() pero no hay manera de que funcione. Ni tansolo accediendo al supuesto primer elemento con "(0)"

```
IE.document.getElementByClassName("tarifas-index")(0)
```

También he visto gente que hace un foreach seleccionando por tagName y recorre la coleccion de elementos seleccionados para conmprobar con un If si .className == a la que deseamos.
Algo mas o menos así:

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://www.salvadorescoda.com/tarifas/index.htm"
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readystate = 4
'------------------------

'La siguiente linea es la que causa el error
For Each itemEle In IE.document.getElementByTagName("input")
    If itemEle.className = "campocodigo" Then
        itemEle.Value = "prueba"
    End If
Next

Range("A2").Value = valor
```

Pero este codigo no me funciona, especificamente la linea de después del comentario. ¿Que hago mal o no tengo en cuenta? ¿Que solución hay? Nunca he programado con VBA y confieso que después de programar JS y algo de PHP este lenguaje me pone de los nervios. Gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Hola!

Tu código iba bien encaminado, y tu idea de jugar con el *classname* también. El problema es el código fuente de la URL proporcionada. Si lees el código fuente, verás que en realidad el elemento que buscas no está en el propio HTML (yo lo leo con Mozilla Firefox, y no me sale), porque el input que tú buscas, en realidad está dentro de un frame que se carga en la principal. Es decir, está en otro documento (si sabes JS y PHP estoy convencido de que sabes más que yo de esto de los documentos, frames y demás, pero espero haberme explicado, yo de PHP y JS ni idea, puro VBA es lo mío).

Sabiendo esto, antes de intentar conseguir el elemento, tienes que acceder al documento del frame. En concreto, el frame que te interesa se llama **mainFrame**.

Mi código es una copia del tuyo, pero ampliando un poco. Por resumir, los pasos son:

1. Navegamos a la URL objetivo
2. Seleccionamos el documento principal de la URL
3. Dentro de ese documento principal, seleccionamos el frame objetivo
4. Una vez dentro del frame, seleccionamos el documento que compone el frame
5. Seleccionamos el Input objetivo, y escribimos lo que queremos (en este caso, **prueba**)

Y ahora el código. Espero que te pueda servir. Modifícalo para tus necesidades.

> **IMPORTANTE:** Tienes que activar dos referencias en la librería VBA. Las librerías son:
>
> 1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
> 2. Microsoft Internet Controls

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código:

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim DOC As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String


url = "http://www.salvadorescoda.com/tarifas/index.htm"
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate url

While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set DOC = IE.document

Dim iFrameDoc As HTMLDocument
Set iFrameDoc = DOC.frames("mainFrame").document 'especificamos el nombre del frame
If iFrameDoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No existe ningún frame con el nombre especificado."
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim itemEle As Object

'ya estamos en el frame, ahora podemos conseguir el elemento INPUT
For Each itemEle In iFrameDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If itemEle.getAttribute("class") = "campocodigo" Then
        itemEle.Value = "prueba"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'<----------resto de tu código------->


IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

Lo que yo consigo ejecutando el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva, y te animo a seguir con VBA, que es un lenguaje muy puñetero, pero a la larga creo que merece la pena.

Un saludo.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** OP tiene un problema con IE 11, porque no le reconoce los frames. Vamos a probar con otra manera de llamarlos, a ver si cuela.

> CÓDIGO VERSIÓN IE 11

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim DOC As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String

Set IE = Nothing
Set DOC = Nothing

url = "http://www.salvadorescoda.com/tarifas/index.htm"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate url

While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set DOC = IE.document.frames


Dim iFrameDoc As HTMLDocument

Set iFrameDoc = DOC.Item("mainFrame").document 'especificamos el nombre del frame
If iFrameDoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No existe ningún frame con el nombre especificado."
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim itemEle As Object

'ya estamos en el frame, ahora podemos conseguir el elemento INPUT
For Each itemEle In iFrameDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If itemEle.getAttribute("class") = "campocodigo" Then
        itemEle.Value = "prueba"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'<----------resto de tu código------->


IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: Vaya, es verdad! No me había percatado del frame!
En cuanto a las referencias, no tenia ni idea! Las he marcado tal como muestras y en el mismo orden d prioridad.
Pese que no estoy familiarizado con las palabras clave y peculiaridades de VBA entiendo tu código pero al ejecutarlo me aparece un error:  

        Se ha producido el error '-2147352319 (80020101)' en tiempo de ejecución:
        Error en el método 'frames' de objeto 'JScriptTypeInfo'

Y la linea que da el error es:  

        Set iFrameDoc = DOC.frames("mainFrame").document

¿Como es posible que a mi me de error?

Comment: Ese error a veces a mí me aparece cuando ya tengo cargada en la memoria alguna instancia de Internet Explorer, de otros códigos o similares. Vamos a hacer una prueba. Reinicia tu equipo y prueba a ejecutar el código, a ver si te falla en la misma línea. ¿Qué versión de Internet Explorer usas?

Comment: Lo de las referencias es MUY útil, porque cuando activas la referencia, entonces se activa el Intellisense, ([más info en inglés aquí](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/visual-basic-editor/intellisense.htm)). Y se evitan errores de escritura, aparte de poder definir las variables como interesa, en vez de definiciones genéricas tipo Object o Variant. Por ejemplo, en tu código original escribiste `IE.document.getElementByTagName("input")` y el correcto es `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")` (una s al final de element), y eso lo detecté gracias a Intellisense :)

Comment: He reiniciado y nada. Uso IE 11. Interesante... Y que son exactamente las referencias? Lo que mas extraño se me hace de VBA es la interfaz en la que se trabaja, al menos en Excel...

Comment: Pues ahí sí que estoy sorprendido. Yo también uso IE 11 y acabo de ejecutar el código sin problemas. Prueba a ejecutar el código paso a paso, con la tecla F8, a ver si así te da error. Ve fijándote a ver si cuando se carga la página, aparece algo raro. Si ambos tenemos el mismo IE pero te da error, quizás haya algún complemento o algo que interfiera. Además, que te de error tipo Javascript es lo que me choca. ¿Puedes colgar un pantallazo de IE justo en el momento en el que te da error?

Comment: Respecto a las referencias, son bibliotecas de objetos adicionales con los que trabajar. VBA es un lenguaje de programación orientado a objetos, y usando referencias, tienes más objetos disponibles.

Comment: Y una cosa más. Respecto al error, ¿te lo da Visual Basic o te lo da Internet Explorer?

Comment: Es Visual Basic quien me lo da. He probado depurando paso a paso y sigue ocurriendo, te adjunto imagenes:
[Depuración linea error](https://ibb.co/gPBTDc).
[Otro F8 > Aparición del error](https://ibb.co/gOLYeH).
Aunque al depurar paso a paso he notado que se salta la linea en la que declaras iFrameDoc como objeto de tipo HTMLDocument, no se si es normal y en realidad sí la ha declarado o si no lo ha hecho por algún motivo y es el causante del error...
En cuanto a las referencias: entiendo, entiendo!

Comment: Puf, pues pocas ideas me quedan. Quizás sea por tiempo de carga? prueba a añadir `Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:30"))` justo después de la línea `IE.navigate url`. Si no, he colgado otra versión del código, a ver si te funciona. Prueba ambas cosas. Mira mi respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Hacerle esperar no soluciona el problema y la linea en la que declaras el objeto del navegador en el nuevo codigo me da error '-2125463506 (8150002e)'. "Error de Automatización". Escucha, no te preocupes, te estoy muy agradecido por tu ayuda! Y si, VBA es un lenguaje muy puñetero, pero ahora me pica la curiosidad, de hecho es posible que le pueda sacar partido para el curro, así que gracias por los ánimos y ayuda! Saludos!

Comment: Ei, no entiendo porque pero ya funciona. Muchas gracias!